# How do I convert an Appender 'class' attribute from Log4j v1 to v2?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'm attempting to remediate a webapp using Log4j v1 by upgrading it to Log4j v2.  I've been stuck for 6 months on configuration.

Today's questions involve Appender classes.  The Log4j v1 properties configuration I'm converting contains lines like

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
```

following the pattern documented in the [v1 JavaDocs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html) as

```
log4j.appender.appenderName=fully.qualified.name.of.appender.class
```

The use of the fully qualified class name makes a certain amount of sense, because it makes the selection of Appender unambiguous: Log4j knows what the Appender is because it can check the classpath for a class of that name that subclasses log4j.Appender.

I cannot convert this 'class' attribute to Log4j v2 using the available documentation.  The Log4j v2 [configuration documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) has absolutely zero information on a 'class' attribute for Appenders.  There is a 'type' attribute, which is completely unexplained but which may conceivably be a similar concept.  It obviously cannot be a full stand-in for 'class', however, since it is ambiguous and does not have any obvious mechanism for relating it to an actual Java class file.

The configuration documentation leaves the reader with four obvious but unanswered questions:

1. Was a 'class' option to an Appender required in Log4j v1 configuration?
2. Is a 'class' option to an Appender required in Log4j v2 configuration?
3. Assuming the answer to 2) is "no," based on examples, then how do Log4j v2 configuration files specify which Appender, in the sense of an actual Java file containing a subclass of `log4j.Appender`, a given line of configuration refers to?
4. Whether a through a 'class' option or otherwise, how is the equivalent of a Log4j v1 Appender 'class' implemented in Log4j v2 XML?

**Update** I've discovered that on the Log4j docs page dealing with [migration], there's an example under the header **Sample 4 - Migrating an AsyncAppender and TTCCLayout configuration** that shows an Appender configuration in XML format in both the v1 syntax and v2 syntax.

The v1 example shows this:

```
<appender name="TEMP" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
```

which is similar to the Properties line I have.  The v2 example, however,

```
<Appenders>
    <File name="TEMP" fileName="temp">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%r [%t] %p %c %notEmpty{%ndc }- %m%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
```

shows nothing that corresponds to the `class` attribute of the v1 syntax.  Nonetheless, there **must be** some mechanism for Log4j to know exactly which Appender is being referenced; i.e. what actual code to run when this Appender is invoked.  Because this example is unexplained, I'm still at a complete loss to understand how to make this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

In Log4j2 all components present in a configuration are implemented as [Log4j 2 plugins](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html). Hence you don't need to know the fully qualified class name of the component, but just the plugin name.

For example, to send your logs to the application's standard output:

- in Log4j 1.x you use the concrete class `org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender`:

  ```
  log4j.appender.appender_name = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
  ```
- in Log4j2 you use an appender called `"Console"`, which in the concise XML configuration format gives you:

  ```xml
  <Console name="appender_name" />
  ```

  or in the strict configuration format:

  ```xml
  <Appender type="Console" name="appender_name" />
  ```

The plugin names are widely documented in the [Log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). If you are curious about the fully qualified class name of the component, you can browse the Javadoc: e.g. the [`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/ConsoleAppender.html) is annotated with `@Plugin(name = "Console", ...)` and provides the "Console" plugin.

However you don't really need to know the FQCN of the components to use them.

PS: To convert a simple `log4j.properties` file to a `log4j2.xml` file you can use the [`Log4j1ConfigurationConverter`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/config/Log4j1ConfigurationConverter.html) from the `log4j-1.2-api` artifact:

```
java -cp ... org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1ConfigurationConverter \
--in log4j.properties --out log4j2.xml
```